# How to parse one array at a time from External JSON file in Intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hi All  I am parsing an external JSON file for animations. It's twitter tweets like below format.

```
[
 {
"title": "Don't forget to stop by the @SabaSoftware stand D52, LEARNTEC 4-6 Feb, #LEARNTEC_news",
"name": "Saba ",
"screen_name": "SabaSoftware",
"image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3684179000/4f4577bfda1612442ad6f8d1d737c78e_normal.jpeg"
 },
 {
"title": "Our #webinar is right around the corner, Feb. 12. See a live demo of #SabaCloud, succession &amp; workforce planning &amp;http://t.co/uYPV5PdPMm",
"name": "Saba ",
"screen_name": "SabaSoftware",
"image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3684179000/4f4577bfda1612442ad6f8d1d737c78e_normal.jpeg"
 },
 {
"title": "Exhibitors relaxing after a hard days work.  Thanks #learntec2014 for the entertainment. http://t.co/7Y70PVKQeu",
"name": "Saba ",
"screen_name": "SabaSoftware",
"image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3684179000/4f4577bfda1612442ad6f8d1d737c78e_normal.jpeg"
 },
 {
"title": "Live band at the exhibitor evening after a successful day at #learntec2014 http://t.co/Y0ScjbUAZU",
"name": "Saba ",
"screen_name": "SabaSoftware",
"image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3684179000/4f4577bfda1612442ad6f8d1d737c78e_normal.jpeg"
 },
 {
"title": "Check out @Bersin tips for building a successful #talentmanagement approach http://t.co/27rbzMUagz",
"name": "Saba ",
"screen_name": "SabaSoftware",
"image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3684179000/4f4577bfda1612442ad6f8d1d737c78e_normal.jpeg"
 }
]
```

I am trying to parse above JSON file and i wanna read one array at a time and show that data in html file after some Interval again read next array item data and show them in html file.
How i am trying to do is like below.

```
  var index;
  var tweets = [];
  $.getJSON(jsonpath, function( result ){

    var tlength = result.length-1;

        for(var i=0; i< tlength; i++)
        {
               index = i;
               tweets = result;
               loadtweet();  
        }
}

function loadTweet(){       
    $('.bubblecontainer').html();

    var tweet = tweets[index];

    $('.bubblecontainer').html('<div class="twitter-list"><ul><li class="pulse"></li</ul></div>');
    setTimeout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.twitter-list ul li').append('<img class="slideDown" src="'+ tweet.image +'" alt="">');},500);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.twitter-list ul li').append('<p class="bigEntrance"><strong>'+ tweet.name +'</strong> @ '+ tweet.screen_name +'</p>');},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.twitter-list ul li').append('<p class="slideLeft">'+tweet.title+'</p>');},1500);
    },6000);
}
```

But when i run this all of the tweets are coming at a time and they are appending every time.Where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
var tweets;
    var i =0;
    var tlength;
    var list;
    $.getJSON(jsonpath, function( result ){     
        tlength = result.length-1;      
        tweets = result;
        $('.bubblecontainer').html('<div class="twitter-list"><ul><li class="pulse"></li</ul></div>');  
        loadtweet();            
    });

    function loadtweet(){                       
        $('.twitter-list ul li').append('<img class="slideDown" src="'+ tweets[i].image +'" alt="">');
        $('.twitter-list ul li').append('<p class="bigEntrance"><strong>'+ tweets[i].name +'</strong> @ '+ tweets[i].screen_name +'</p>');
        $('.twitter-list ul li').append('<p class="slideLeft">'+tweets[i].title+'</p>');
        if(i<tlength){
            setTimeout(loadtweet, 2000);            
        }
        i++
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling loadtweet for all tweets at the same time. Rather than calling `loadtweet()` call `setTimeout( loadtweet, 1000*i );` (adjust timing to suit)

Comment: it wont work bro because i wanna loop contnously through JSON and needs to show one object data at a time

Answer (score 0):

All the tweets will be loaded as you're running the `loadTweet` function for each consecutive tweet one after the other. Your timeouts are therefore all initiated at the same time and all the tweets will appear after 6 seconds. Try something like this.

```
$.getJSON('path/to/json', function( result ) {

    var container = $('.bubblecontainer').html('<div class="twitter-list"><ul></ul></div>'),
        list = container.find('ul');

    for(var i=0; i < (result.length - 1); i++)
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            loadtweet(result[i], list);
        }, (i * 6000));
    }
}

function loadTweet(tweet, list)
{
    var $tweet = $('<li />').html(
        '<img class="slideDown" src="'+ tweet.image +'" alt="">' +
        '<p class="bigEntrance"><strong>'+ tweet.name +'</strong> @ '+ tweet.screen_name +'</p>' +
        '<p class="slideLeft">'+tweet.title+'</p>'
    );

    list.append($tweet);
}
```

Comment: everytime only last tweet is coming, i also faced the same problem when i got one tweet at a time

Comment: @Venkat move the $('.bubblecontainer').html(...) out of the loadTweet function. That's what is causing that as the entire HTML contents are everwritten on each call to loadTweet.

Comment: If i put that bubblecontainer outside all tweeets are concatenating

Comment: Looking at it, of course they will. They are appending to the first `<li>` not creating their own. Updating code to help you out.

Comment: can we join over chat room